# How can I play different videos at same time?

Tags: archlinux, omxplayer

I use `omxplayer` to play videos. But `omxplayer` can play one video at same time. I typed `omxplayer 1.avi --win 0,0,500,500` on terminal and first video started. After that I typed `omxplayer 2.avi --win 500,500,900,900` on different terminal and it said Have a nice day. How can I play different videos at same time ?

my system is : `Linux alarmpi 4.1.6-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 22 12:18:37 MDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`

omxplayer : `Build date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 18:18:14 -0600 Version   : 4d8ffd1 [master]`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `omxplayer --layer n` option where **n** means the priority. higher number means top layer.

on first tab run `omxplayer --layer 1 --win .....` and on second tab run `omxplayer --layer 2 --win .....`.

second video will be on top of first video.